# How to get uploaded file in Struts action

Tags: jsp, servlets, file-upload, struts-1

This is the jsp page to upload the file:

```
<html:form action="/process.do?method=upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">       

     File :<input type="file" name="filename" /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" style="margin: 40px 0 0 160px"/>

</html:form>
```

This the action forward method which processes the uplaoded file:

```
public ActionForward upload(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws Exception 
     {
      System.out.println("Inside ProcessAction class upload method ");


    String filePath="";
     boolean isMultipartContent = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
     System.out.println("isMultipartContent -->>> "+isMultipartContent);
     FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<FileItem> fields = upload.parseRequest(request);
                 System.out.println("file name -> "+request.getParameter("filename"));
                System.out.println("fields --> "+fields.size());

                 Iterator<FileItem> it = fields.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("inside while -->>> ");
                    FileItem fileItem = it.next();
                    filePath = fileItem.getName();
                    System.out.println("inside while filePath -->>> "+filePath);
                }

            } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    System.out.println("filePath -->>> "+filePath);

}
```

output:

> Inside ProcessAction class upload method
>   isMultipartContent -->> true
>   file name -> null
>   field-. 0
>   filepath -->>>

I am not able to grab the uploaded file path. I'm uploading file to the server from my local machine. Need help

Comment: is this the correct way of submitting the form in struts 2?

Answer (score 0):

There is easier way to upload the file in struts 1. You can use `FormFile`

For the usage, you can take a look at
http://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsFileUpload